# Timeline Entries for multiple Complication Families

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

My Complication and Time Travel worked perfectly when I only had `.ModularLarge`.

I wanted to add `.ModularSmall` as an option, so I tried to modify my code a few different ways, but it is no longer working as expected.

What's happening now is that Time Travel will work for the first entry in the array produced from `getTimelineEntriesForComplication`, but the next entries never appear when doing Time Travel, so the Complication just stays on the first entry.

**Timeline** *tried using `if` statement*:

```
func getTimelineEntriesForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, afterDate date: NSDate, limit: Int, withHandler handler: (([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void)) {

    guard let headers = headerArray, texts = body1Array, dates = body2Array else { return }

    var entries = [CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]()
    for (index, header) in headers.enumerate() {
        let text = texts[index]
        let date1 = dates[index]
        let headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: header as! String)
        let body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: text as! String)
        let timeTextProvider = CLKTimeTextProvider(date: date1 as! NSDate)
        let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
        let template2 = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallStackText()
        template.headerTextProvider = headerTextProvider
        template.body1TextProvider = body1TextProvider
        template2.line1TextProvider = headerTextProvider
        template2.line2TextProvider = body1TextProvider
        template.body2TextProvider = timeTextProvider

        if complication.family == .ModularLarge {
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date1 as! NSDate, complicationTemplate: template)
            entries.append(timelineEntry)
            handler(entries)
        }
        if complication.family == .ModularSmall {
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date1 as! NSDate, complicationTemplate: template2)
            entries.append(timelineEntry)
            handler(entries)
        }
        else {
            handler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's happening is Time Travel will work for the first entry in the array produced from getTimelineEntriesForComplication, but the next entries never appear when doing Time Travel, so the Complication just stays on the first entry.

There's a bug in your `getTimelineEntriesForComplication` code. You've returned an array with only one entry because you returned *inside* the for loop:

```
for (index, header) in headers.enumerate() {
    if complication.family == .ModularLarge {
        let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date1 as! NSDate, complicationTemplate: template)
        entries.append(timelineEntry)
        handler(entries)
    }
}
```

Restructure your code to look like this:

```
for (index, header) in headers.enumerate() {
    if complication.family == .ModularLarge {
        let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date1 as! NSDate, complicationTemplate: template)
        entries.append(timelineEntry)
    }
}
handler(entries)
```

Comment: Code works, but just wondering your opinion on if `if` statement or `case switch` is better to use in the methods.  And then if you would choose `if`, would you use just `if` or would you use `if else`?

Comment: Personally, I think the switch statement is easier to read and maintain, and it has more code safety built in to it.  More errors could happen with `else if` blocks.